# How to redirect output of multiple commands to one file?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I have a bash script that contains the following two commands:

```
ssh host tail -f /some/file | awk ..... > /some/file &

ssh host tail -f /some/file | grep .... > /some/file &
```

How can I make the output of both commands be directed into the same file?

Comment: Keep in mind that if both commands are running in the background, you cannot predict how the output from the two commands will be interleaved in `/some/file`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Note you can reduce the number of ssh calls:

```
{  ssh host tail -f /some/file | 
     tee >(awk ...) >(grep ...) >/dev/null
} > /some/file &
```

example:

```
{ echo foobar | tee >(sed 's/foo/FOO/') >(sed 's/bar/BAR/') > /dev/null; } > outputfile
cat outputfile
```

```
fooBAR
FOObar
```

Comment: how can i get the pid of this?

Comment: If you background the whole thing (`>outputfile &`), the pid will be in `$!`

Comment: yeah, but my ssh is inside two for loops, $! doesn't give me the right pids

Comment: You could get it directly: `ssh_pid=$( pgrep -f "ssh host" )`

Answer (score 44):

Either use 'append' with `>>` or use braces to encompass the I/O redirections, or (occasionally) use `exec`:

```
ssh host tail -f /some/file | awk ..... >  /some/file &
ssh host tail -f /some/file | grep .... >> /some/file &
```

or:

```
{
ssh host tail -f /some/file | awk ..... &
ssh host tail -f /some/file | grep .... &
} > /some/file
```

or:

```
exec > /some/file
ssh host tail -f /some/file | awk ..... &
ssh host tail -f /some/file | grep .... &
```

After the `exec`, the standard output of the script as a whole goes to `/some/file`. I seldom use this technique; I usually use the `{ ...; }` technique instead.

Note: You do have to be careful with the braces notation. What I showed will work. Trying to flatten it onto one line requires you to treat the `{` as if it were a command (followed by a space, for example) and also to treat the `}` as if it were a command. You must have a command terminator before the `}` — I used a newline, but an `&` for background or `;` would work too.

Thus:

```
{ command1;  command2;  } >/some/file
{ command1 & command2 & } >/some/file
```

I also have not addressed the issue of why you have two separate `tail -f` operations running on a single remote file and why you are not using `awk` power as a super-`grep` to handle it all in one — I've only addressed the surface question of how to redirect the I/O of the two commands to one file.

Comment: none of this works. I also tried { command1 ; command 2 } > /some/file, but it doesn't work

Comment: @user2864207, note that the one-line use of `{ list of commands; inside braces; }` **must** end with a semicolon, as illustrated in Jonathan's last sentence.

Comment: You do have to be careful with the braces notation. What I showed will work. Trying to flatten it onto one line (why — why on earth would two separate pipelines be flattened onto one line? have you no respect for readability or comprehensibility?) requires you to treat the `{` as if it were a command (followed by a space, for example) and also to treat the `}` as if it were a command. You must have a command terminator before the `}` — I used a newline, but an `&` for background or `;` would work too.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Could you point to where the problem you described above with flattening onto one line would be explained in more detail?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: I'm not sure what extra detail you're looking for.  Any standard shell text book should cover the issue — it was a facet of the Bourne shell in the early 80s, and was continued into the POSIX shell, and therefore is a part of Korn shell and Bash.  You could study the POSIX specification of the [shell language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/shell.html); you'd find it codified there (but it isn't an easy read).  Which aspect of the examples in the question and comment aren't clear enough?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I was curious about *(...) requires you to treat the { as if it were a command (...)* statement specifically as it's rather strange to treat something that should be part of syntax as a command. I was wondering if it's something similar to `[` which is a real binary?

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: it is loosely similar to `[`, but `{` is not a binary.  In fact, it is a [reserved word](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_04) in the shell — which I'd forgotten or had not appreciated.  See also the information on [compound commands](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04).

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost: The GNU Bash manual has a section on [Command Grouping](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping) which states more or less what I stated — it is corroboration, but not a lot more informative (though it is not clear what else could be used to explain it; there isn't much more to be said unless you grovel through the shell grammar).

Comment: As a noob, this taught me so much. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer to this is to probably get rid of the `ssh .... | grep ...` line, and modify the `awk` script in the other command to add the functionality you were getting from the `grep` command...

That will get rid of any interleaving issues as a bonus side-effect.

Comment: i can't get rid og the ssh .. | grep line. That's the wholw point the script