# how to log several commands from a shell script to a log file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh

have several commands in a shell file that I would like to log and show on screen. but some commands results I want to NOT show on screen and some I want to - but all of them need to be logged.

I can use tee or > or >> etc..

```
script.sh | tee -a logfile
```

but that does not allow me to pick and choose what shows on screen and what goes into logs.

example script - what I have now (each line is different and looks inefficient)

```
echo "setting date" | tee log.txt #show on screen and log
`date` | tee -a log.txt # screen and log
echo "setting name" | tee -a log.txt #show on screen  
`who am i` >> log.txt | only log
```

I have a several commands like this - and am wondering if there is a efficient way to append to log AND/OR append to log while showing on screen.

OR do I have to modify and make a call in each line ?

Users will not be able to modify this script.

Comment: ps: I understand using exec >> --> but that won't display anything. and i want to be selective in what is displayed and what does not.

Comment: So.... on the commands you don't want to log, don't use `tee`, and the ones you do want to log, use `tee`. What more are you looking for? Perhaps I don't understand the question.

Comment: my question is - do I need to then make a tee or >> reference for each command in the shell script ? if I 20 commands, then each command has to have a tee or >> ?

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355264/how-to-redirect-output-of-multiple-commands-to-one-file maybe?

Comment: Yeah... I mean, that's pretty simple, right? `command >> my.log` or `command | tee -a my.log` or `command` depending on your needs. I suppose you could write a function that takes in the stdout and a boolean whether you want to log it or not, but that seems even more cumbersome.

Comment: I am trying to do this inside the script.. and not have to expect my users to do the tee or >> when they run. right now the best I have is "exec &> >(tee $0.log)" as my first line.

Answer (score 0):

When you do not want to tell with each command who you like it logged, decide what you want to use most of the time. Is it `tee`? Try this:

```
function doit {
   echo "Normal (both)"
   # Some more commands without explicit rediection for both strout and logfile
   echo "only stdout" >&3
   echo "Only logfile" >> $0.log
}
exec 3>&1
echo " === Screen output"
doit | tee -a $0.log
echo " === Content file"
cat $0.log
```

Output

```
=== Screen output
only stdout
Normal (both)
 === Content file
Only logfile
Normal (both)
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your responses. after a lot of additional research - I decided to pick portions from the answer at [How do I write stderr to a file while using "tee" with a pipe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692000/how-do-i-write-stderr-to-a-file-while-using-tee-with-a-pipe) - the post from Anthony.