# How do I pass output of (both) piped instructions to file?

Tags: linux, shell, stdout, pipeline

I have two commands say cmd1 and cmd2, wherein i perform

```
time cmd1 | cmd2
```

I want to get something like

```
cmd1 >> file.out and {time cmd1 >> file.out} | cmd2 >> file.out
```

so can someone suggest how it is actually done? 
edit: as Anthony's answer below suggests, tee works here but if i write

```
time cmd1 |tee -a file.out | cmd2 >> file.out
```

then it only writes the output of cmd1 to file.out and cmd2 to file.out, whereas i also want the output of {time cmd1} to that file.

I am using bash shell on Ubuntu Mate. If the time keyword complicates it, please suggest some method to time the execution and do the exact operation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to redirect output of multiple commands to one file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355264/how-to-redirect-output-of-multiple-commands-to-one-file)

Comment: Is it a duplicate? That question has two commands, i am asking how to get the output of before the pipe and after the pipe to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want the output of `cmd` to be
written to `file.out` and *also* used as the input to `cmd2`. For this case, you could try inserting the `tee` command (with the `-a` option to append) into your command pipeline:

```
cmd1 | tee -a file.out | cmd2 >> file.out
```

#### Example

```
$ printf "one\ntwo\nthree\n" | tee -a file.out | sed 's/.*/\U&/' >> file.out

$ cat file.out
one
two
three
ONE
TWO
THREE
```

### Answer to edited version of the question

The following construct should do what you want:

```
{ time cmd1; }  2>> file.out | tee -a file.out | cmd2 >> file.out
```

Since the [`time` utility provided by Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html#Pipelines) operates on the **complete pipeline**, curly braces are used to [group these commands](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/CompoundCommands) so that they can be considered as a whole. Note: the terminating semi-colon (`;`) is required before the closing brace.

The standard out stream of `cmd1` is piped through to the `tee` command but since Bash’s `time` utility prints its timing statistics to *standard error*, the file descriptor `2` is redirected so that the timing statistics are appended to `file.out`.

#### Modified version of previous example

```
{ time printf "one\ntwo\nthree\n"; }  2>> file.out | tee -a file.out | sed 's/.*/\U&/' >> file.out
```

Comment: This is what I wanted. I found about tee but wasn't sure how to use it together. Let me try this :)

Comment: There is a slight twist though. I have edited the question again. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @Vivek That's a substantially different question. The use of the `time` command complicates things. I'd also advise editing the question to indicate what shell you're using. Since, you're using Linux, `time` is most likely provided by the Bash shell as a *shell keword*.

Comment: Yes its a bash shell on Ubuntu Mate. I have edited now the question.

Comment: @Vivek I've updated my answer to answer the revised question – though you should try to describe your question as completely as possible before posting it.

Comment: Thank you @Anthony. I wasn't aware that having `time` in cmd1 would complicate the thing so much, so I wrote the question differently the first time.

Comment: @Vivek No worries. Asking – and answering – questions is a learning experience.  If this answer worked for you, you should [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) by clicking on the check mark to the left.  This marks the question as *answered* and (with upvotes) is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites. On the other hand, you could wait and see if someone else comes along with a more useful answer.  Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!